# Indexing a heroku site on google

Tags: django, heroku

I am a beginner and just made a website using django and python and host this https://randoms77.herokuapp.com/ website to the heroku but whenever I search it on google it's shows no results.Please tell me how can we index a heroku site on google

Comment: See https://www.google.com/webmasters/  you need something like this on your webpage `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="YOURTOKEN" />` and on the google dashboard you need to add the website URLs you own. Furthermore it will take a while for it to be indexed.

Comment: Thanks, I will go to the google search console and will register it but another question is:- Any site can be indexed on google or thier are some rule? Also, I indexed my site and it says url is on google but I can't find it by searching

Answer (score 1):

I have the problem that it does not let me index my urls, it tells me that it has not been able to obtain data and less with a sitemap

Answer (score 1):

Google generally doesn't allow a sub domain into its services. I think a heroku app with heroku sub domain cannot be indexed. Possible if have your own domain.

Comment: seems more of a comment

Comment: new user stack overflow did not let me post a comment

Comment: No bro... You can do index the website with the heroku subdomain. Google allows it!

Answer (score 1):

You can index your app in Heroku subdomain using [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about).

1. Go to Google Search Console and click `Start Now`.
2. Since you don't have a DNS and the website is hosted on heroku with `herokuapp.com` subdomain, switch to the `URL PREFIX` tab.
3. Enter you website's address, e.g. `https://example.herokuapp.com` and click continue.
4. Now, there are number of verification methods. But I prefer to insert the `meta` tag in the home page of the website. So, copy the HTML meta tag and insert it in your website(don't forget to update the app).
5. After updating your app, go back to the page and click on verify.